# Realm get added object with objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How to get the object that was added to the realm

I add the realm with following code:

```
 -(void) onLikeClick:(id *)sender{
    NSLog(@"like btn clicked");
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    StickerModel *sticker = [[StickerModel alloc]initWithImagePath:imagePath];
    sticker.imagePath = imagePath;
    [realm addObject:sticker];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

}
```

And want to get how many objected that was added into the `realm` with

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [realm accessibilityElementCount];
}
```

And to get the specific items at specific index so I could use that as a `collectionViewDataResource`

But How to? didn't find any api of realm there, thanks

Comment: http://www.iostute.com/2015/12/ios-objective-c-tutorial-for-realm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count:

```
RLMResults<StickerModel *> *stickers = [StickerModel allObjects];
return stickers.count;
```

For getting object of a specific index, you would better to get it from a sorted collection:

```
RLMResults<StickerModel *> *stickers = [[StickerModel allObjects] sortedResultsUsingKeyPath:@"ID or another field" ascending:YES];
return stickers[indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this ,  it will give all the objects in your RealM DB..

```
RLMResults * tableDataArray= [YourDB allObjects];
NSArray *peopleObjects = [tableDataArray valueForKey:@"self"];
```